# Matching a string to a regex from html input

Tags: java, regex

I'm having a little trouble figuring out what to do.

Basically using java I'm trying to:

- Reading in the html from a website
- I want to find the content after a certain string in this case being

  ```
   title="
  ```
- Store that in a string.

The first and last steps are simple for me but I'm having no luck (and never had with regex).

I believe this is the beginning of what I need:

```
   String regex = "(?<=title=\")\\S+";
   Pattern name = Pattern.compile(regex);
```

After that I have no clue. Any help?

Comment: Use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) instead.  (Here we go again...)

Comment: I suggest using some library for this (you'll get even XPath support): [HttpUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/), [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/), [NekoHtml](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String EXAMPLE_TEST = "......";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=title=\")(\\S+)")
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST);
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Note: You might consider to use regex pattern `(?<=title=\")([^\"]*)`

Comment: Do we want the whole title or just until the first whitespace?

Comment: @maerics - I believe OP didn't ask to change regex pattern but (s)he wants help with rest of code to get match to variable, or so...

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> result_list = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("title=\"(.*)\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher("title=\"test\"");
boolean result = m.find();

while(result)
{
    result_list.add(m.group(0));
    result = m.find();
}
```